# When using twilio's php notify API, how do you set your callback URL?

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

I have the following code and it sends SMS notifications to my phone:

```
$notification = $twilio->notify->services($serviceSid)
                                    ->notifications->create([
                                        'toBinding' => $batch,
                                        'body' => $txt,
                                        'statusCallback' => 'http://postb.in/b/jarblegarble' // <-- this doesn't work
                                    ]);
```

However, even though the sending works, I can't seem to figure out their callbacks.

I'm scouring through their docs and I can't find how to set the callback URL. I see some of their resources use "url" while others use "statusCallback" (heck, one seems to use "redirect"). That being said, I can't seem to post to postb.in using them -- there must be a way to check the status of my notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out I was wrong on two fronts.

1) The callback URL needs to be passed to your messaging service this way:

```
$notification = $twilio->notify->services($serviceSid)
    ->notifications->create([
        'toBinding' => $bindings,
        'body' => $txt,
        'sms' => ['status_callback' => 'http://your_callback_url' ]
    ]);
```

2) postb.in wasn't working! I was testing the code above, after being assured by twilio support that it was valid, I decided to try and post to my own server and just capture the POSTed content. Sure enough, it was working as they suggested.

Edit: It wasn't clear to me at the time but the callback URL will be called for each SMS sent out for each status update. So that means queued, sent, and delivered. I initially thought that I'd just get a status update for the batch itself as I don't necessarily care for the status of up to 10,000 txt messages.

Comment: I setup the status_callback URL but not receiving any data in $_REQUEST.

Answer (score 1):

Your example passes the [`statusCallback` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-confirm-delivery-php) of the *individual* SMS service API to the *universal* notify API. This mixing won't work. The individual SMS service sets up a callback for that one particular message, which isn't efficient for batch sends. The universal notify API, in contrast, relies on [web hooks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/webhook-events#post-callbacks), which are globally configured per service.

The simplest thing to do, in your case, is to use the individual SMS service API:

```
$message = $twilio->messages->create('+15551234567', [ 'body' => 'Hi',
    'from' => '+15559876543',
    'statusCallback' => 'http://postb.in/b/jarblegarble' ]);
```

To use the universal notify API, you'll need to set the `PostWebhookUrl` to the target URL when *creating* the notification service, and arrange for the code at that URL to handle `onMessageSent` messages. More at the "web hooks" URL above.

*Caveat emptor: haven't tried any of this, and I haven't used Twilio in literally eight years, but the above is my theoretical understanding.*

Comment: I'll have to look at a global webhooks then! The system needs to send messages in batches so setting individual callbacks isn't ideal (and requiring one call to the API per number could take a lot of time and timeout). Thanks for the direction.